# Выпадающее меню общее для всех страниц

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

> Есть выпадающий список с ссылками на модели кроватей (вынесется на отдельную страницу),как сделать для всех страниц сайта 1 выпадающий список и на каждой странице select выбирался по умолчанию. Остальные блоки подключаю к страницам через include, а этот не получается из-за  `<option selected="selected">`

```html
<form onSubmit="PutToHidden()">
<fieldset class="form_zakaz_border">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><p>Модель</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <select  id="select" onchange="Change(this);">
   <optgroup label="Двухъярусная кровать" >
    <option selected="selected" value="6300" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/belava">Белава</option>
    <option value="6300" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/dvuxyarusnaya_krovat_kupe">Купе</option>
    <option  value="9900" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/dvuxyarusnaya_krovat_provans">Прованс</option>
   </optgroup> 
   <optgroup label="Детская кровать">
    <option value="3800" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/detskaya_mebel/detskie_krovati_iz_massiva">Массив</option>
    <option value="4800" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/detskaya_mebel/detskaya_krovat_raduga">Массив Радуга</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
  </td>
  
  
 </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Может потому, что у Вас почему-то сразу два `<option selected="selected">`. Вы на верстку внимательно посмотрите.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd  убрала

Comment: Лиана,  да, здесь вижу - убрали. Пробовали подключать еще раз? метод php-шный(это я про инклюд)? Код функции `PutToHidden()` заодно выложите пожалуйста. И заодно код, что парсит `data-link`. Где-то есть код, что берет значения из этих атрибутов, и наверное релокейтит? В общем вопросов много. Просто информации мало. Пример, вопроизводящий проблему, Вы не выложите. А посему это придется делать нам.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd Создала новый вопрос и оформила подробно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850460/286144