# Одно выпадающее меню для всех страниц, select по умолчанию

Tags: jquery, select

> Есть выпадающий список с ссылками на модели кроватей (вынесется на отдельную страницу),как сделать для всех страниц сайта 1 выпадающий список и на каждой странице select выбирался по умолчанию. Остальные блоки подключаю к страницам через include, а этот не получается из-за  `<option selected="selected">`.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //выбранный чекбокс добавляет к сумме:       
  $("#yslygi:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });
  $("#yslygi2:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });
  //общая сумма
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}



$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="select" onchange="Change(this);">
   <optgroup label="Двухъярусная кровать" >
 <option selected="selected" value="6300" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/belava">Белава</option>
 <option  value="6300" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/dvuxyarusnaya_krovat_kupe">Купе</option>
 <option  value="9900" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/dvukhyarusnaya_krovat_provans">Прованс</option>
 </optgroup> 
<optgroup label="Детская кровать">
 <option value="3800" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/detskaya_mebel/detskie_krovati_iz_massiva">Массив</option>
 <option value="4800" data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/detskaya_mebel/detskaya_krovat_raduga">Массив Радуга</option>
</select>

<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option value="0">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select><br/>

<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
</select><br/>

Борт  <input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="bort" />100<br/>
Борта <input type="checkbox" id="yslygi2" name="bort2" />100<br/>
Стоимость <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
```

Comment: что должно выбираться в селекте "по умолчанию"?

Comment: @Igor Название страницы,например,"Белава", его значение value="6300" подставлялось в формулу, если переходить на модель кровати через выпадающее меню, был адрес страницы: data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/belava"